# How to calculate yearly values from monthly data in three dimensional matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I have monthly rainfall data in three dimensional matrix and I want to calculate total annual rainfall from monthly rainfall data. 
Three dimensional data (180 x 360 x 120), where 180 x 360  is 1 degree by 1 degree grids and 120 is number of months (for 10 years).

Now I want to covert monthly values into years by summing the monthly values of each year (12*10=120) so that after summing my final output will be 180 x 360 x 10.
How would I do this in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% create sample data
tt = rand(180,360,120);

% aggregate monthly data to yearly
ttt = reshape(tt,180,360,12,[]);    % reshape to separate individual months
ttt = sum(ttt,3);                   % sum over years
ttt = squeeze(ttt);                 % squueze 4D array into 3D array
```

Hope this helps.